# How to assign the same value to multiple resistors in an LTSPICE circuit

Tags: ltspice, spice

I have around 10 resistors in a circuit, all with the default value "R".

I defined the directive

```
.param R=100
```

Upon running the simulation, I get the error message

> Can't find definition of model "R"

Is there a general way to assign a value to all Rs at once or do I have to do it by hand one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the *value* of those resistors to `R=R`. So, where you used to set the value to a number without a preceding `R=`, now the value has to start with `R=`

It may be more clear to use `.param Rdefault=100` and `R=Rdefault`.

Make sure the `.param Rdefault=100` is a spice directive, not a comment.

***In answer to using curly braces { and }:***
For both versions of LTspice (IV and XVIII) applies that when you want to assign a **numerical** value in the form of an equation, you have to use burly braces.
For example, when setting the value to `{arctan(1)*4}`.
In OP's question, setting the value to `{Rdefault}` will work too.

However, for **non-numerical** values, you need to (and for numerical values you can) precede the value with `R=` . When preceding it with `R=`, you do not need to use the burly braces:
E.g. when setting the value to `R=arctan(1)*4*time`

Therefore my suggestion to always use the preceding `R=`

Comment: Doesn't it need to be `R={R}`? Or does that depend on which version of LTSpice?

Comment: @ThePhoton Please check my update. It's not version dependent, but expression dependent.

Comment: All of them are numerical values, `time` translates in a dynamic value. `R=` only means you can assign expressions that are `time`-dependent, that's all. The curly braces can exist, or not for behavioural expressions, but are mandatory for fixed values since those are meant to be parsed at the beginning and replaced with their resulting value -- curly braces (or single apostrophe, `'`) do that. In behavioural expression they're not needed since the parser knows that the expression after equal needs to be evaluated, whether statically (like `{x}`), or dynamically (like `R=x*time`).